# How to sort a views result based on user roles weight?

Tags: sorting, drupal, view, drupal-7

Is there a way to sort asc/desc the views result based on the user role's weight. We tried php code as the sort criteria. We returned the weight of the user role as the output, but the order is not changing as expected.

Comment: Refer: https://drupal.org/comment/5978650#comment-5978650

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following php function.....actually I only made it a function because its tidier that way and I needed to use it in multiple views, but you could use this code directly in your view. Ideally this should probably be in a module.

```
function get_role_weight($userId){

  $users = user_load($userId);
  $userRole = $users->roles;
  $arr = Array();

  foreach($userRole as $row){
    $roleID = user_role_load_by_name($row)->rid;
    $role = user_role_load($roleID);
    $arr[] = $role->weight;
  }

  sort($arr);

  return $arr[0];
}
```

**How its done**

1. Add a new "Global:PHP" field to your list of fields
2. Exclude this new field from the display - we don't want to show it just use it later for ordering
3. Put this code in the "Value code:" field: `return get_role_weight($data->uid);`
4. put the following code in the "Output code:" field `<?php print $value; ?>`
5. Finally all you need to do is add a new "Global:PHP" field to your sort criteria and make it sort "ascending" then use the following code in the "Sort code:" field: `if ($row1->php < $row2->php) { return -1;} else { return 1;}`